# Planning to use ehcache-2.10.1 in my Java project that already has hibernate-4.1.4 as a dependency. How do I get rid of possible conflict?

Tags: java, hibernate, dependencies, ehcache

Here's the problem. Hibernate-4.1.4 has ehcache-core-2.4.3 that I just can't exclude easily (we don't use Maven...) and I'm not sure if just leaving it as is would cause a conflict with ehcache-2.10.1.

If worse comes to worst, I may opt to exclude ehcache-core-2.4.3 from hibernate and manually include ehcache-2.10.1 to my build path - however, I'm not sure if ehcache-2.10.1 will be compatible with hibernate 4.1.4.

Any other alternative solution?

Answer (score 0):

Right, you want to drop the 2.4.3 from the classpath. How you do that depends on your build system, can't help you without knowing what you actually use there.

I *think* 2.10.1 will work out of the box should you run without clustering. But I *could* well be wrong. Replacing one with the other, you should know straight away though. (there has been some changes around the statistic APIs that have been an issue, but I can't recall when these happened).